# How to make Column names bold in XLSX?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spreadsheet, xlsx

I am using the XLSX library in Angular with TypeScript for creating spreadsheet reports. I want to make the column names bold. How can I achieve that?

```
export_to_excel() {
  this.downloadSpinner = true;
  this.reportService.getBCPayoutReportData()
    .subscribe({
      next: data => {
        if (data.length != 0) {
          let XlsMasterData = data
          const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(XlsMasterData);
          this.fixWidth(workSheet);
          const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
          XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'SheetName');
          XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'report.xlsx');
        } else {
          this.showSwalmessage("No record Found!", "", "warning", true);
        }
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        this.showSwalmessage("Something Went wrong", error, "warning", true);
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.downloadSpinner = false;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are using community(free) version of XLSX package its unavailable to make cell bold. The cell styling and other additional features to modify cell formats are only available in Pro version of the library. Please check here https://sheetjs.com/pro/.

Also you can custom color to make alike bold .Please see the example https://angular6-export-xlsx-xrheux.stackblitz.io

Also you can use package exceljs. It provides a lot of features